# Create hash with ASP.NET MVC for Lemon Squeezy X-Signature

Tags: c#, hash, asp.net-mvc-5, cryptography

The following function is for receiving a [Lemon Squeezy webhook](https://docs.lemonsqueezy.com/guides/developer-guide/webhooks) request:

```
public ActionResult lsHook(LemonsqueezyWebhook lemonsqueezyWebhook)
{
...
}
```

It works as expected in terms of the payload data. Lemon Squeezy uses X-Signature to help confirm the request is actually from Lemon Squeezy, not a phishing site. The following is their code example:

```
$secret    = '[SIGNING_SECRET]'; // from your webhook settings
$payload   = file_get_contents('php://input');
$hash      = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret);
$signature = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SIGNATURE'] ?? '';

if (!hash_equals($hash, $signature)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid signature.');
}
```

Here is my C# code to do the same in `ActionResult lsHook(LemonsqueezyWebhook lemonsqueezyWebhook)`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("X-Signature")
if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("X-Signature"))
{
    foreach (string sValue in Request.Headers.GetValues("X-Signature"))
    {
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine).Append(sValue);
    }
    Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string sPayload = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] payloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sPayload);
        byte[] secretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysecret");

        // Combine payload and secret
        byte[] data = payloadBytes.Concat(secretBytes).ToArray();

        // Hash the combined data
        byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
        
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + "hash: ").Append(BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower());
    }
}
```

Here is what I got from one request for sb:

```
      dab5a3c5f205f60aa09ab00098f67917e8fcc6b05e64d510b656d82f35bca97c
hash: 3ee77ac08f050e1338ca3a4a8c0162eb8ff9aa1fb7d89418881492a52da1cc37
```

They do not match. `sPayload` looks correct. It is the json object. Could anyone offer a hint about the possible cause?

**Update:**

After `var sha256 = SHA256.Create()` was replace with `var sha256 = HMACSHA256.Create()`, I got the following:

```
      10de6aa343a95017309a7e7d3b683fb35afa4be9f67c41c2d87ae1f9872e0914
hash: 9dceac34439623bff6549b2dd264672e0cc20910
```

Comment: The PHP code uses HMAC/SHA256, the C# code SHA256, i.e. different functionalities, which leads to different results. Try [`HMACSHA256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256) in the C# code.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you. I updated my post with your suggestion. Could you take a look at it to see if I did it correctly?

Comment: You need to set the key instead of concat.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you. I edited my post according to your suggestion.

Comment: NP. I'm always using `\`\`\`` around my code blocks by the way, because that makes it easier to indicate the language such as `\`\`\`php` for PHP and `\`\`\`none` for the output. Gave a hint right before your comment...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I set the key: sha256.Key = secretBytes where sha256 is HMACSHA256, the generated hash still has much fewer bytes. SHA256 does not have the property Key.

Comment: Try `new HMACSHA256(secretBytes)`. The link in my last comment also contains a sample code. Have a look at it.

Comment: @Topaco Hallelujah!!! That is the answer: `new HMACSHA256(secretBytes)`. Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Huh? Even if you set the key after construction it should result in the same answer. Or did you first enter the data and then set the key perhaps? And that first "hash" result looks like 20 bytes or so which would indicate SHA-1. Weird, by default HMAC-SHA-256 should output 32 bytes which would encode to 64 hex characters.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I remember I set the key before `byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(payloadBytes);`. I hesitate to try to reproduce it. TBH, I am doing all of this on the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in the posted code was that the C# code only calculated the SHA256 value instead of the HMAC/SHA56 value.
After fixing this, the key was not specified correctly and the `Create()` method was applied, which requires the specification of the digest, which was missing.

---

Determining an HMAC/SHA256 can be implemented on .NET as follows using [`HMASCSHA256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256):

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
...
byte[] secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some secret");
byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some payload");
using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(secret)) 
{
    byte[] hash = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(payload);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(hash)); // 22A2E09F97E933DB48BA6EF24C6BE11A5A10024BD9A6A18E662E94BF3C35F257
}
```

---

The key can of course also be set later:

```cs
...
using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256()) 
{
    hmacSha256.Key = secret;
    byte[] hash = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(payload);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(hash)); // 22A2E09F97E933DB48BA6EF24C6BE11A5A10024BD9A6A18E662E94BF3C35F257
}
...
```

---

Note that `HMACSHA256.Create()` does not work on .NET 5+ (*System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This platform does not allow the automatic selection of an algorithm*).
On .NET Framework it works, but returns an HMAC/SHA1 value by default:

```cs
...
using (var hmacSha256 = HMACSHA256.Create()) 
{
     hmacSha256.Key = secret;
     byte[] hash = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(payload);
     Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(hash)); // FF81B9A37F9DA6EA0DE2CFF78216B697722E9A08 // for ByteArrayToString() see https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/9014097
}
...
```

This is probably the cause of the shorter hash in your environment. In order for HMAC/SHA256 to be used, it must be explicitly specified:

```cs
...
using (var hmacSha256 = HMACSHA256.Create("HMACSHA256"))
{
    hmacSha256.Key = secret;
    byte[] hash = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(payload);
    Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(hash)); // 22A2E09F97E933DB48BA6EF24C6BE11A5A10024BD9A6A18E662E94BF3C35F257 // for ByteArrayToString() see https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/9014097
}
...
```

The reason is that `HMACSHA256.Create()` calls `HMAC.Create()`, and the latter requires a specification of the digest, otherwise it defaults to HMAC/SHA1, s. [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hmacsha256.cs,15).
Since `new HMACSHA256(secret)` works in all environments, it is probably most robust to use this (in accordance with the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=net-8.0#examples) in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you very much for the highly educational answer. Greatly appreciated.